# Shutdown IoT device from code

Tags: c#, iot, systemmanagement

What I have is: VS 2017 Community, C#, Raspberry 3, IoT-Extension referenced.
I want to shutdown the Raspberry from code.
What I have found on the web everywhere is this:
Edit the AppManifest. Add 
  ...IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot">
(- which already was there when I looked into it)
Then add:

```
<iot:Capability Name="systemManagement"/>
```

But: "iot:Capability" stays undercurled, saying, that it "has invalid child element 'Capabilities' in namespace 'http:... appX/manifest/iot/win10'

I had already 2 other capabilites selected

```
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
```

Can they interfere?
I could not find this error somewhere else on the whole web. Would be great if someone had an explanation for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you add `xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"` before `IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot"`?

Comment: Yes, it is all complete...

Comment: Are your sure it is an error? It is a warning for me and I test on Raspberry Pi 3, I can shut down the device from my app. It works.

Comment: The blue curly line remains under "iot:Capability" and in the .cs code it says the "ShutdownManager does not exist.."

Comment: Add this name space: `using Windows.System;`

Comment: Incredible, that's it! Thank you so much for sticking to my question! I never would have found it (Windows.System seems so basic and already there...). Do you think I can leave the app with this "warning"? If you want to post it as answer I would upvote of course. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad to help you. Yes, you can leave the warning there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use ShutdownManager to manages the shutdown of devices, you need:

1. Reference Windows IoT Extension SDK (v10.0.10240.0 or later)
2. Add the following to application Package.appmanifest: `<iot:Capability Name="systemManagement"/>`
3. Add this name space: `using Windows.System;`

For more detailed information, see [ShutdownManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.shutdownmanager).